# jquery.ui.map openInfoWindow on marker creation

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-maps

I'm using jquery.ui.map and trying to call openInfoWindow on a newly created Marker.

This works and adds my my marker, but how can I call openInfoWindow on creation of this marker?

```
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker',{'position': event.latLng,'draggable': true,'bounds': false}).dragend(function() {
                    dragEndFunc(this);
                }).click(function() {
                    markerClickFunc(this);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Original answer:
try using `google.maps.event.trigger(your marker, 'click');`

Oh I see (you don't have the marker object) - you could just assign it after invoking addMarker, like this:

```
var mymarker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': '20,30', bounds': true});
mymarker.click(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': 'Hi ma!'}, this);
});
new google.maps.event.trigger(mymarker[0],'click');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess my problem is that I don't have a reference to the newly added marker. The "your marker" param in your example is what I'm missing once I've called the above code. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but not quite sure what.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Seems like you can supply a 3rd param as a func to run now. See the location of the newMarkerFunc below.

```
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker',{'position': event.latLng,'draggable': true,'bounds': false},function(map, marker) {
                    newMarkerFunc(marker);
                }).dragend(function() {
                    dragEndFunc(this);
                }).click(function() {
                     markerClickFunc(this);
                });
```